# How to add a new colum in one data frame based on time intervals in anohter data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames. One of them (df1) summarized when a fish was detected in a specific area. The other one summarises periods in which there were divers in this particular area. As an example:

```
datetime<- c("2016-08-01 06:00:02","2016-08-01 09:31:27","2016-08-01 13:34:02","2016-08-01 16:45:15","2016-08-02 09:07:12","2016-08-02 11:25:02","2016-08-02 17:25:02","2016-08-02 21:50:00")
df1<-data.frame(datetime)
df1$datetime<- as.POSIXct(df1$datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
start<- c("2016-08-01 07:00:00","2016-08-01 08:30:00","2016-08-01 10:30:00","2016-08-01 16:00:00","2016-08-02 10:00:00","2016-08-02 16:00:00")
end<- c("2016-08-01 08:30:00","2016-08-01 10:00:00","2016-08-01 12:00:00","2016-08-01 17:30:00","2016-08-02 11:30:00","2016-08-02 17:30:00")
divers<-c(6,2,8,12,8,7)
df2<-data.frame(start,end,divers)
df2$start<- as.POSIXct(df2$start, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df2$end<- as.POSIXct(df2$end, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

df1
        datetime
1 2016-08-01 06:00:02
2 2016-08-01 09:31:27
3 2016-08-01 13:34:02
4 2016-08-01 16:45:15
5 2016-08-02 09:07:12
6 2016-08-02 11:25:02
7 2016-08-02 17:25:02
8 2016-08-02 21:50:00

df2 # Notice there are four periods with divers on 2016-08-01 and only two on 2016-08-02.

            start               end         divers
1 2016-08-01 07:00:00 2016-08-01 08:30:00      6
2 2016-08-01 08:30:00 2016-08-01 10:00:00      2
3 2016-08-01 10:30:00 2016-08-01 12:00:00      8
4 2016-08-01 16:00:00 2016-08-01 17:30:00     12
5 2016-08-02 10:00:00 2016-08-02 11:30:00      8
6 2016-08-02 16:00:00 2016-08-02 17:30:00      7
```

I would like to add the info about the divers' presence in a new column in my data frame df1. In this new column in df1, let's call it "divers", I would like to show the number of divers present at the time of the fish's detection. If when the fish was present according to df1, there weren't divers in the area according to df2, then add 0 to "df1$divers". If when the fish were present according to df1, there were 5 divers, add 5 to "df1$divers". As an example of what I would expect:

```
datetime<- c("2016-08-01 06:00:02","2016-08-01 09:31:27","2016-08-01 13:34:02","2016-08-01 16:45:15","2016-08-02 09:07:12","2016-08-02 11:25:02","2016-08-02 17:25:02","2016-08-02 21:50:00")
divers<- c(0,2,0,12,0,8,7,0)
result<-data.frame(datetime,divers)
result$datetime<- as.POSIXct(result$datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

result
             datetime divers
1 2016-08-01 06:00:02      0
2 2016-08-01 09:31:27      2
3 2016-08-01 13:34:02      0
4 2016-08-01 16:45:15     12
5 2016-08-02 09:07:12      0
6 2016-08-02 11:25:02      8
7 2016-08-02 17:25:02      7
8 2016-08-02 21:50:00      0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R, we could use `sapply` over `datetime` column in `df1` and find out the time which lies in between `start` and `end` time of `df2`, get the corresponding `divers` and `sum` them.

```
df1$divers <- sapply(df1$datetime, function(x) 
                     sum(with(df2, divers[x >= start & x <= end])))

df1
#             datetime divers
#1 2016-08-01 06:00:02      0
#2 2016-08-01 09:31:27      2
#3 2016-08-01 13:34:02      0
#4 2016-08-01 16:45:15     12
#5 2016-08-02 09:07:12      0
#6 2016-08-02 11:25:02      8
#7 2016-08-02 17:25:02      7
#8 2016-08-02 21:50:00      0
```

---

We could achieve the same using the `dplyr`/`purrr` alternative with `map_dbl`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 %>%
mutate(divers = map_dbl(datetime, ~ sum(with(df2, divers[. >= start & . <= end]))))
```

In OP's example it is not necessary to do `sum` of `divers` since there is no overlap in `start` and `end` time but in case if there is an overlap it is better to have `sum` which would add all the divers in that time period.